# how to delete data from multiple relative tables in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have few tables having constraint relationship with foreign keys like below:

1. parent_table id(primary key)
2. parent_child c_id(primary key) and id(reference from parent_table)
3. child ch_id(primary key) and c_id(reference from parent_child table)

Now i need to delete a record from parent_table including with child tables which are having same record. But here i am getting challenge is parent_table references parent_child table but parent_child table references child table with another column.

How can i identify exact value from child tables to delete that particular record.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have gone through the 'on delete cascade' method but my tables does not contain this and there is no possibility to alter to include this.

Answer (score 0):

follow what is discussed in [this link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6254523200346736598) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196261/deleting-rows-from-parent-and-child-tables) hope it helps